# function to read a string and get the length - C

Tags: c, strlen

I'm having issues writing a C function that reads a string from STDIN, and returns the length of said string... Suggestions?

Comment: no, actually...sounds useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, simply use strlen from the C standard library:

```
#include <string.h>
```

So the strlen() function is available. You just need to pass a char pointer, and it will return the string length:

```
size_t length = strlen( myStr );
```

Note that size_t is an integral type.

By the way, if you don't know about this function, you should really dig into the C library, and lear about the basic functions it provides.

Comment: where has this function BEEN all my life?!?!?!

Comment: Haha beat me by a min Macmade :P

Comment: @tekknolagi: It's been right here all along: `size_t strlen(char* s) {size_t l = 0; for (;*s;++s,++l); return l;}`

Comment: Note that Michael's is the *slowest* `strlen()` version around. You can easily make it about 10 times faster.

Comment: @Philip: it was just a joke, but I think coming up with one that's 10 times faster (and remain bug-free) may be trickier than you might first guess. Particularly for someone who hadn't even heard of `strlen()` until yesterday.

Comment: @Michael: unfortunately, I know. See glibc's `strlen()` at http://tsunanet.net/~tsuna/strlen.c.html for details. I once did a timing analysis and compared it to the naive version, and it turned out that it's *a lot* faster (by a constant factor that I've forgotten by now). On the other hand, if I need optimization in `strlen()`, I've probably done something wrong in the first place... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  // not totally necessary just for EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // check number of params
    if (argc != 2) {
        // argv[0] is name of exe
        printf("usage: %s string", argv[0]);

    // check length of first command line parameter
    } else {
                    // strlen does the counting work for you
        unsigned int length = strlen(argv[1]);

        printf("Length is %d\n", length);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Note that strlen returns a size_t type, which may be larger that an unsigned int.

Comment: Indeed but thought that a non primitive type might be confusing for someone new.

Comment: @Macmade: that would be one hell of an argument!

Comment: @Macmade: An ordinary `int` is guaranteed to be able to store every possible array size. Since "strings" are arrays (or better: can always be treated as such), `strlen()` can't overflow an `int`.

Comment: @Philip: I don't believe that's true.

Comment: @Michael: You are right, it's not. See my latest question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004415/why-size-t-when-int-would-suffice/