# Why size_t when int would suffice for the size of an array?

Tags: c, int, standards, size-t

The C standard guarantees that an `int` is able to store every possible array size. At least, that's what I understand from reading §6.5.2.1, subsection 1 (Array subscripting constraints):

> One of the expressions shall have type ‘‘pointer to object type’’, the other expression shall
>   have integer type, and the result has type ‘‘type’’.

Since we shall use `int`s as array subscripts, why are we supposed to use `size_t` to determine the size of an array?

Why does `strlen()` return `size_t` when `int` would suffice?

Comment: size_t is typically unsigned.  As string size of -1 seems somewhat meaningless, so why would I want to support it?

Comment: Not typically. It's required to be an unsigned type. A few buggy implementations used to have signed `size_t`, and it resulted in extremely serious exploitable vulnerabilities.

Comment: And there is `malloc` as well which takes `size_t` as argument. And it is not trivial to know what to use as array subscript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174850/type-for-array-index-in-c99

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The term "integer type" doesn't mean `int` - for example, `char`, and `short` are integer types.

Just because you can use an `int` to subscript an array doesn't necessarily mean that it can reach all possible array elements.

More specifically about `size_t` vs. `int`, one example would be platforms where `int` might be a 16-bit type and `size_t` might be a 32-bit type (or the more common 32-bit `int` vs 64 bit `size_t` difference on today's 64-bit platforms).

Answer (score 6):

integer type is not necessarily an "int". "long long" is an integer type too, as is "size_t".

Arrays can be larger than 2GB. This property is quite handy for those who write memory hungry programs, e.g DBMS with big buffer pools, application servers with big memory caches etc. Arrays bigger than 2GB/4GB is the whole point of 64 bit computing :)

size_t for strlen(),  at least sounds compatible with how C standard handles arrays, whether it makes practical sense or not, or whether somebody have seen strings that large, is another question.

Comment: While they can in principle exist, it's best for programs to forbid strings larger than `INT_MAX` in size, since `snprintf` returns `int` and gives an overflow error if the resulting string would be longer (i.e. the best safe way to process strings becomes unusable if you want to allow strings longer than 2GB).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, what you quoted from the standard does not make any references to type `int` specifically. And no, `int` is not guaranteed to be sufficient to store the size of any object (including arrays) in C.

Secondly, C language does not really have "array subscriptions" specifically. The array subscription is implemented through pointer arithmetic. And the integral operand in pointer arithmetics has `ptrdiff_t` type. Not `size_t`, not `int`, but `ptrdiff_t`. It is a signed type, BTW, meaning that the value can be negative.

Thirdly, the purpose of `size_t` is to store the size of any object in the program (i.e. to store the result of `sizeof`). It is not immediately intended to be used as an array index. It just happens to work as an array index since it is guaranteed that it is always large enough to index any array. However, from an abstract point of view, "array" is a specific kind of "container" and there are other kinds of containers out there (lists-based ones, tree-based ones and so on). In generic case `size_t` is not sufficient to store the size of *any* container, which in generic case makes it a questionable choice for array indexing as well. (`strlen`, on the other hand, is a function that works with arrays specifically, which makes `size_t` appropriate there.)

Comment: Given that `calloc`, `qsort`, and `fread`/`fwrite` all use pairs of `size_t` values for element size and element count, I disagree with your statement that `size_t` is not intended to be used as an array index. Also the integer operand in pointer arithmetic and have any integer type, not just `ptrdiff_t`, but the result of subtracting pointers has type `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: @R..: All these functions are *specific* functions fundamentally tied to arrays, which is what makes it OK to use `size_t` with these functions. I never disagreed with that. I'm just saying that in a more generic context, when one needs to index a "container" (*some* container, which might be an array today, but become a list tomorrow), `size_t` is not an appropriate type.

Comment: Many people these days got used to see `size_t` as some kind of "ultralarge" type which is sufficient to index "the entire memory", thus making it sufficient for all in-memory counting/indexing purposes. In reality, the concept behind `size_t` is very different. It is not guaranteed to be able to index "the entire memory"

Comment: What would you use instead? `uintptr_t` would work if it exists, but it's not required to exist. As far as I'm concerned systems where `size_t` is smaller than the pointer size are a legacy consideration and not really worth considering for "tomorrow".

Comment: R..: It is not a matter of whether `size_t` is sufficient, it is a matter of using the right tool for the job. Your reasoning sounds like "microscopes will always be sufficiently sturdy to be used as nutcrackers so I'll just use them to crack nuts". In application-specific code you normally *already have* a type that you use to count all specific entities. That is the type you should use for all kins of counting/indexing of such entities. Could be simple `unsigned int`, could be some `TNutCount` with something hiding behind the typedef.

Comment: I think we'll need to disagree - I find useless app/library-specific types like that one of the worst offenses in C code, and I don't believe they can be defined in any reasonable way that scales beyond the original author's (lack of) imagination except with `size_t` or `intmax_t`/`uintmax_t`. And the latter should probably not be used in public interfaces since a platform ABI might change its max integer type size as it evolves...

Comment: Why would not size_t be sufficient to  index the entire memory? It can at least index the virtual address space of the process, and this is "entire memory" a process can get. Or do you have counterexamples?

Comment: @Vladislav Vaintroub: It can't. `size_t` by definition can hold he size of the largest continuous object your implementation allows you to create. That's all it can do. Nowhere it is guaranteed that you can create an object that occupies the entire memory, so there's no guarantee that `size_t` is sufficient to index the entire memory. Integer type that can index the entire memory is called `uintptr_t`, not `size_t`. `size_t` is in general case smaller than "the entire memory".

Comment: Segmented memory platforms will typically have such "small" `size_t`, like DOS/Win16 or like IBM 128-bit platforms. These are my "counterexamples". However, I don't care about any "counterexamples". Counterexamples don't mater. What matters is that `size_t` implements a very specific concept. And that concept has nothing to to with generic counting. Which immediately makes `size_t` inappropriate for generic counting. Whether it is "sufficient" or not does not matter at all.

Comment: @R..: I don't understand your last sentence. On any typical flat-memory platform `size_t` will normally have the same size and range as `uintptr_t`. So "evolution" will change the size of both, thus making them both inappropriate for public interfaces. Yet, you somehow state that only the latter is not suitable for such use (???).

Comment: Thanks for segmented memory examples. Personally, I mostly about much smaller concept - continous memory allocations, i.e malloc(), mmap(), MapViewOfFile() etc, or even static buffers on stack.  Those are defined in terms or size_t,  so far newest from the C standard did not make it into Posix and Win32 interfaces :)

Comment: In my last sentence I was referring to the situation on a particular platform (perhaps CPU architecture/ISA and ABI would be more clear than simply "platform" in conveying what I meant). Sure new archs (like x86_64 vs i386) can have larger pointers and `size_t`, but the sizes of these types will not change *within a given arch/ABI* because they're defined by the ABI. On the other hand, some ABIs may intentionally leave certain types like `int_fastNN_t` and `intmax_t` flexible to allow some flexibility for expansion without breaking the majority of existing object code/libs.

Comment: 6.5.6/9: says of pointer subtraction, "If the result is not representable in [`ptrdiff_t`], the behavior is undeﬁned". From this it is clear that `ptrdiff_t` is *not* guaranteed to be large enough to contain any offset in an object. It is also false that `ptrdiff_t` is "the integer operand" in pointer arithmetic. Any integral type can be used for pointer addition, the standard only makes `ptrdiff_t` a special case for subtraction. `size_t` is the type defined to be usable for any positive offset in an object, not `ptrdiff_t`. It doesn't "happen" to work, it's defined to. `offsetof` uses it too

Comment: If you were designing a system to represent arbitrary containers (perhaps including files, for example), then you might want to represent their sizes and offsets by something other than `size_t`, and in that context I suppose you would also represent the sizes of arrays using that other representation. But the C languages doesn't concern itself with what you might like to do for other containers, it concerns itself with arrays, and it provides `size_t` for their sizes and indexes (but unfortunately provides no type for arbitrary signed offsets).

Comment: @Steve Jessop: The bit with `ptrdiff_t` I borrowed by mistake from C++ specification, where the equivalent declarations of built-in pointer arithmetic operators use `ptrdiff_t` as their arguments. (Yes, I know that this question is tagged [C].) The rest of your comment is basically retelling what I said originally. Any object in C can be seen as an "array of bytes", which is what creates that parasitic link between "object size" and "array index". Nevertheless, I don't see any convincing reasons to rely on that parasitic link, even though it is guaranteed to always exist.

Comment: The concepts of "object size" and "element count" are two totally different completely unrelated concepts. And `size_t` is attached to the former.

Comment: @AndreyT: It's attached to both by the standard library, which is part of the language. @Steve: While you're correct that the standard does not require any otherwise-valid pointer difference to fit in `ptrdiff_t`, there's no way for a conforming program to determine whether the difference between two pointers to elements of the same array will overflow and invoke UB, so any implementation where the result can overflow `ptrdiff_t` is broken to the point of being virtually unusable. This is a quality-of-implementation thing, but personally I would just assume pointer diffs can't overflow.

Comment: @AndreyT: object size and element count are not completely unrelated concepts. The size of an array *in elements* is equal to its element count. The size of an array *in bytes* is equal to its element count times the size of each element in bytes. That's what arrays are. There may be some higher abstraction which you would like to treat arrays as a special case of, but the C language doesn't, so your preferences have little to do with C and certainly don't justify everyone stopping using `size_t` to do what it was designed for. In other languages, maybe.

Comment: @R..: ah, is there no conforming way to work out the max value of `ptrdiff_t`? If you could do that, then you could choose not to allocate arrays any bigger than that when you're planning to later do pointer subtraction within them. Arrays that you're not planning to do subtraction could be bigger. Even if that were possible, I'd agree it's a nasty restriction and one that implementors would do well to lift.

Comment: @R..: hmm, there is, `PTRDIFF_MAX`. Seems to me you could use this in place of `SIZE_MAX` when checking for overflow prior to dynamically allocating memory. Library functions could document this as a restriction on inputs if it needs to do pointer subtraction - no oversized arrays (oversized in whatever type the subtraction will be done elements or bytes).  As you can tell, I *don't* do this, I make the same assumption you recommend, but it doesn't seem difficult to me to do it strictly-conformingly. What have I missed?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Firstly, the relation between size and count you describe is, again, exactly what I described in one of my previous comment and what I consider a "parasitic link" between size and count. Secondly, the whole point I'm trying to make is that at application level the matter of choosing the proper count/index type *is* undoubtedly a matter a higher abstraction level than the low-level properties of C language. Yes indeed, it has little to do with C, and I thought it was sufficintly clear from that part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the C Standard was written, it was common for machines to have a 16-bit "int" type, and be incapable of handling any single object larger than 65535
bytes, but nonetheless be capable of handling objects larger than 32767 bytes.
Since arithmetic on an unsigned int would be large enough to handle the largest
size of such objects, but arithmetic on signed int would not, size_t was defined
to be unsigned so as to accommodate such objects without having to use "long"
computations.

On machines where the maximum allowable object size is between INT_MAX and
UINT_MAX, the difference between pointers to the start and end of such an
object may be too large to fit in "int".  While the Standard doesn't impose
any requirements for how implementations should handle that, a common approach
is to define integer and pointer wrap-around behavior such that if S and E
are pointers to the start and end of a char[49152], then even though E-S
would exceed INT_MAX, it will yield a value which, when added to S, will
yield E.

Nowadays, there's seldom any real advantage to the fact that size_t is an
unsigned type (since code which needs objects larger than 2GB would often
need to use 64-bit pointers for other reasons) and it causes many kinds of
comparisons involving object sizes to behave counter-intuitively, but the
fact that sizeof expressions yield an unsigned type is sufficiently well
entrenched that it's unlikely ever to change.

Answer (score -3):

size_t is a typedef of unsigned integer (such as int or long).

In some 64bit platforms, int can be 32bit, while size_t can be 64bit.

It is used as a more standard way for size.

Comment: _"size_t is a typedef of unsigned int."_ - not always true.

Comment: No, `size_t` is a typedef for some unsigned type. The type hiding behind `size_t` might even be non-standard, i.e. it might not be expressible as `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` etc.

Comment: In theory, `size_t` might be `unsigned long long` or even `uintmax_t`.